# How to check default SIM card selected for make call

Tags: android, provider, phone-call, sim-card

Is there any way to check default SIM card is selected for make call ?

I am using the below code for make call,

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
          intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNO));
          intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
          if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
              // TODO: Consider calling
              //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
              // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
              //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
              //                                          int[] grantResults)
              // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
              // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
              return;
          }
          context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: what API version is it being worked on?

Comment: @nandsito: 23 (Marshmallow)